# Problematic 3D models that will collapse while being 3D printed by SLA technology

Tags: 3d-models, support-structures, sla, print-failure

I'm working on an algorithm that predicts the probability of collapse for 3D models while being 3D printed by SLA technology.

I'm looking for some 3D model that will collapse while being 3D printed. I wonder if there are any standard ones.

#### Note

Maybe I can rotate the famous [teapot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)#/media/File:Utah_teapot_(solid).stl) in way that it will collapse...

Comment: Interesting. It's maybe better to have an actual question for a title and an example of one a model that is 'collapsed' to better understand what you're searching for. Also in what format? Are you training a prediction model using deep learning or using another statistical or mathematical approach?